# C# code first grpc : custom protobuf converter for DateTime

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net, protobuf-net.grpc

I'm using something like this in dotnet asp net core 6:

```
<PackageReference Include="protobuf-net.Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.152" />
<PackageReference Include="protobuf-net.Grpc.AspNetCore.Reflection" Version="1.0.152" />


[DataContract]
public class TaskItem
{
    //other properties omitted

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Now, when I call the service with grpcurl

```
"DueDate": {
  "value": "458398",
  "scale": "HOURS"
}
```

And in the generated proto file

```
import "protobuf-net/bcl.proto"; // schema for protobuf-net's handling of core .NET types

 message TaskItem {
    //other properties omitted
    .bcl.DateTime DueDate = 5;
```

Is there a way to specify a custom converter so that it will serialize to ISO 8601 string in order to better support cross platform (I'll have some clients in js where having a string is ok since I just need `new Date(v)` and `d.toISOString()`) ?

I know I can just declare DueDate as string, but then the "problem" is that when I use C# code-first client I also need to convert back to DateTime and to string ...

For example, I can do the following with JSON

```
.AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

Comment: You might [edit] your question to give a bit more detail about what framework you are using to create your client and tag the question with those frameworks.  E.g. I don't *think* that ASP.NET Core 6 gRPC uses [tag:protobuf-net] by default, it uses `Grpc.Net.Client` and `Google.Protobuf`, see [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0).  As it is your question might not have enough visibility.

Comment: @dbc I edited the question accordingly, thanks for the suggestions. I hoped that https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell could answer

Comment: This [is explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dates-and-times). Protobuf's native scalar types have no date types. You'll have to change the type from DateTime to an extension type ,google.protobuf.Timestamp

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for commenting on my question. Basically what I'd like is to automatically tranform a DateTime into google.protobuf.Timestamp for every date time property in my code base instead of having to specify it explicitly in all my classes (exactly like I told the JSON serializer/parser to consider enum as strings and not as int)

Comment: Why do you want this? gRPC and protobuf aren't JSON. The API DTOs you use aren't your entities (or shouldn't be). A [Timestamp](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/timestamp) is a predefined Well Known Type which means it's recognized by all gRPC clients. It's a binary type so ISO8601 doesn't apply. It's a UTC value too, so DateTime can't be used unless it's DateTimeKind is Utc. `Local` or `Unknown` will throw errors. If you want to use DateTime, you'll have to add an extra step to convert to UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is *very* different from a JSON type converter. As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dates-and-times) explain the standard way of serializing dates is the `google.protobuf.Timestamp` type. That's defined in the `proto` file. When you use code-first that file is generated by the open source [protobuf-net.Grpc](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc) tool.

To use the `Timestamp` type you need to tell the tool to format that property using a well-known type with the `ProtoMember` attribute :

```
[ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

This is shown in the tool's [Getting Started](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/main/docs/gettingstarted.md) document.

This isn't the default for legacy reasons :

> (for legacy reasons, protobuf-net defaults to a different library-specific layout that pre-dates the introduction of .google.protobuf.Timestamp). *It is recommended to use DataFormat.WellKnown on DateTime and TimeSpan values whenever possible.*

Comment: Thanks for pointing this ! I was reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dates-and-times and this explanation is not there

Comment: @ChristopheBlin I found the explanation in the docs at [Code-first gRPC services and clients with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It certainly wasn't clear from the start though, I found it as I tried to find out what attributes can be used to control the `.proto` file. .NET's gRPC was built on top of Marc Gravell's protobuf-net, so it has highly likely there *was* a way to control code generation